# Is it Possible to get iphone voice mails in app or text messages

Tags: ios

I am working on a app in iOS. In which i need to get voice mails of iPhone and stored in my app and from app If I want to save any of voice mail then select and stored on my server and a sharing and downloading option is also there.

I have searched a lot on Google and StackOverflow, but get reply for security concerns apple, not allow to get messages and emails of iPhone. Is there a way to get this.

Comment: This is not possible due to the sandboxed nature of apps on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to read text messages or voice mails. Apple is very strict on this due to privacy concerns.

You can only access data for which Apple supplies a documented API. You can not access files outside of the sandbox of your app, unless Apple provides an API for it. Using non-documented, private APIs is forbidden by Apple. (See [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).)